# CodeIgniter sessions into database long time

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter, session

I´m working on CI administration and I have one problem - I´m storing sessions in database but it takes really long time to make the query - update takes usually about 3 seconds. Sometimes it decrease to 0.6 but mainly it is about 3 seconds. Do you have any idea how to improve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using Ion_auth ? Can you `SHOW CREATE TABLE` the session table ?

Comment: I´m not sure if I understand you? You want to show the SQL query for creating the table, yes?
Here is the query
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;`

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` is a MySQL command but you gave me a similar query it's good ;) How many rows do you have ? Can you perform a very simple query on it something like `SELECT * FROM ci_sessions WHERE session_id = put_a_real_value_here` and tell me the time it takes ?

Comment: Please turn on CodeIgniters profile `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and see yourself how many queries are sent to the server, observe session variables etc.

Comment: Main page: 3 queries - 2 selects - about 0.1 sec. and third query - update for sessions into database takes from 0.5 sec to 4 seconds... session data aren´t